# Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import axios from "axios";
import Image from "next/image";

//INTERNAL IMPORT
import Style from "../styles/reSellToken.module.css";
import formStyle from "../AccountPage/Form/Form.module.css";
import { Button } from "../components/componentsindex";

//IMPORT SMART CONTRACT
import { NFTMarketplaceContext } from "../Context/NFTMarketplaceContext";

const reSellToken = () => {
  const { createSale } = useContext(NFTMarketplaceContext);
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('"');
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id, tokenURI } = router.query;

  const fetchNFT = async () => {
    if (!tokenURI) return;

    const { data } = await axios.get(tokenURI);

    setImage(data.image);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNFT();
  }, [id]);

  const resell = async () => {
    try {
      await createSale(tokenURI, price, true, id);
      router.push("/author");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error while resell", error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className={Style.reSellToken}>
      <div className={Style.reSellToken_box}>
        <h1>ReSell Your Token, Set Price</h1>
        <div className={formStyle.Form_box_input}>
          <label htmlFor="name">Price</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            min={1}
            placeholder="reSell price"
            className={formStyle.Form_box_input_userName}
            onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className={Style.reSellToken_box_image}>
          {image && (
            <Image src={image} alt="resell nft" width={400} height={400} />
          )}
        </div>

        <div className={Style.reSellToken_box_btn}>
          <Button btnName="Resell NFT" handleClick={() => resell()} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default reSellToken;
```

ReSelling NFT Function is not Working.

Answer (score 0):

your input element seems to be missing these attributes `name={'price'} value={price}`

The onChange handler sets the state to the value of the input provided on client interaction but you haven't provided a value prop/attribute so in essence there's nothing to change. You have to provide a value prop and bind it to the state so when the client changes the value, the state in turn is also changed to the current value, otherwise it stays the same. See it as providing a value to an undeclared variable in some languages
Both the name and value attribute are also useful for form validation and also when sending data to server

Comment: PLease explain, in your answer, why this would work.